# The shuffling order of DataLoader in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am really confused about the shuffle order of DataLoader in pytorch.
Supposed I have a dataset:

```
datasets = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

In scenario I, the code is:

```
torch.manual_seed(1)

G = torch.Generator()
G.manual_seed(1)

ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets,generator=G)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=datasets,sampler=ran_sampler)
```

the shuffling result is `0,4,2,3,1`.

---

In scenario II, the code is:

```
torch.manual_seed(1)

G = torch.Generator()
G.manual_seed(1)

ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=datasets, sampler=ran_sampler, generator=G)
```

the shuffling result is `1,3,4,0,2`.

---

In scenario III, the code is:

```
torch.manual_seed(1)

G = torch.Generator()
G.manual_seed(1)

ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets, generator=G)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=datasets, sampler=ran_sampler, generator=G)
```

the shuffling result is `4,1,3,0,2`.

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, I did a little modification (on scenario II) and inspection:

```
datasets = [0,1,2,3,4]

torch.manual_seed(1)
G = torch.Generator()
G = G.manual_seed(1)

ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets, generator=G)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=datasets, sampler=ran_sampler)
print(id(dataloader.generator)==id(dataloader.sampler.generator))
xs = []
for x in dataloader:
    xs.append(x.item())
print(xs)

torch.manual_seed(1)
G = torch.Generator()
G.manual_seed(1)

# this is different from OP's scenario II because in that case the ran_sampler is not initialized with the right generator.
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=datasets, shuffle=True, generator=G)
print(id(dataloader.generator)==id(dataloader.sampler.generator))
xs = []
for x in dataloader:
    xs.append(x.item())
print(xs)

torch.manual_seed(1)
G = torch.Generator()
G.manual_seed(1)


ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets, generator=G)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=datasets, sampler=ran_sampler, generator=G)
print(id(dataloader.generator)==id(dataloader.sampler.generator))
xs = []
for x in dataloader:
    xs.append(x.item())
print(xs)
```

The outputs are:

```
False
[0, 4, 2, 3, 1]
True
[4, 1, 3, 0, 2]
True
[4, 1, 3, 0, 2]
```

The reason why the above three seemingly equivalent setups lead to different outcomes is that there are two different generators actually being used inside the `DataLoader`, one of which is `None`, in the first scenario.

To make it clear, let's analyze the source. It seems that the `generator` not only decides the random number generation of the `_index_sampler` inside `DataLoader` but also affects the initialization of `_BaseDataLoaderIter`. See the source code

```
        if sampler is None:  # give default samplers
            if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable:
                # See NOTE [ Custom Samplers and IterableDataset ]
                sampler = _InfiniteConstantSampler()
            else:  # map-style
                if shuffle:
                    sampler = RandomSampler(dataset, generator=generator)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
                else:
                    sampler = SequentialSampler(dataset)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
```

and

```
        self.sampler = sampler
        self.batch_sampler = batch_sampler
        self.generator = generator
```

and

```
    def _get_iterator(self) -> '_BaseDataLoaderIter':
        if self.num_workers == 0:
            return _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter(self)
        else:
            self.check_worker_number_rationality()
            return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
```

and

```
class _BaseDataLoaderIter(object):
    def __init__(self, loader: DataLoader) -> None:
        ...
        self._index_sampler = loader._index_sampler
```

- Scenario II & Scenario III

Both setups are equivalent. We pass a generator to `DataLoader` and do not specify the `sampler`. `DataLoader` automatically creates a `RandomSampler` object with the `generator` and assign the same generator to `self.generator`.

- Scenario I

We pass a sampler to `DataLoader` with the right generator but do not explicitly specify the keyword argument `generator` in `DataLoader.__init__(...)`. `DataLoader` initializes the sampler with the given sampler but uses the default generator `None` for `self.generator` and the `_BaseDataLoaderIter` object returned by `self._get_iterator()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However, i have one question. Why do you say the ran_sampler is not initialized with the right generator in my scenario II? What do you mean?

Comment: In your scenario II, `ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets)`.  You did not specify the generator keyword argument in `ran_sampler` initialization and it was initialized with the default generator under the hood.

Comment: I am sorry, but what do you mean by the default generator under the hood? I find that in my scenario II, id(dataloader.generator)!=id(dataloader.sampler.generator).  In fact, I check the source code of RandomSampler(), and I find that the sampler would generate a generator itself. This is exactly what happens in my scenario II.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant. By default, it will create a generator, which is not the one you want.