# The relationship between Dataloader, sampler and generator in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

Supposed I have a dataset:

```
datasets = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

In scenario I, the code is:

```
torch.manual_seed(1)

ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets)
for data in ran_sampler:
  print(data)
```

The result is `1,3,4,0,2`.

In scenario II, the code is:

```
torch.manual_seed(1)

seed=1234
G = torch.Generator()
G.manual_seed(seed)

ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=datasets, 
                        sampler=ran_sampler,
                        generator=G)
for data in ran_sampler:
  print(data)
```

The result is `1,3,4,0,2`. In fact, give any value to the variable `seed`, the result is still `1,3,4,0,2`.

In scenario III, the code is:

```
torch.manual_seed(1)

ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=datasets, 
                        sampler=ran_sampler)
for data in dataloader:
  print(data)
```

The result is `4,1,3,0,2`.

I check the [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/sampler.html#RandomSampler) of `RandomSampler` and find:

```
seed = int(torch.empty((), dtype=torch.int64).random_().item())
generator = torch.Generator()
generator.manual_seed(seed)
```

It shows that `RandomSampler` would create a generator itself if no generator is given. Therefore in theory, my scenario I, II and III would output the same results but scenario III outputs a different results. Why would this happen? I am lost in the source code of `Dataloader` and I am confused about the relationship between Dataloader, sampler and generator.

I have already asked a question about [The shuffling order of DataLoader in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74580942/the-shuffling-order-of-dataloader-in-pytorch). I understand that `Dataloader` would pass the generator to sampler in certain environments but in my scenario III, the `RandomSampler` has a generator already.

Comment: my mistakes. fix it now.

Answer (score 5):

Scenario 3 is actually trickier to investigate than I thought. Let's look at all scenarios one by one. In this answer, "generator" means "random number generator" that is an instance of `torch.Generator`, and **not** [Python's generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator).

## Scenario 1

This scenario is straightforward. When one iterates a `RandomSampler` created without `generator` supplied, the sampler creates its own generator as you pointed out. This creation can be seen inside the `RandomSampler.__iter__` definition:

```py
seed = int(torch.empty((), dtype=torch.int64).random_().item())
generator = torch.Generator()
generator.manual_seed(seed)
```

The result is `1,3,4,0,2`.

## Scenario 2

A generator passed to `DataLoader` is used only to (a) create a `RandomSampler` if `sampler` is not given and (b) generate a base seed for workers when multiprocessing is used. Both uses are described in the docstring. In your code, `sampler` is set to `ran_sampler` and multiprocessing isn't used (the default). Thus, the passed generator `G` has no effect. What was intended is perhaps for `G` to determine the random sampling of `datasets`. In this case, `G` should be passed to `RandomSampler` as follows

```py
seed = 1
G = torch.Generator()
G.manual_seed(seed)

ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets, generator=G)  # G is passed here
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=datasets, 
                        sampler=ran_sampler)  # G is not passed here
for data in ran_sampler:
  print(data)
```

However, this code prints `0,4,2,3,1` which is different from Scenario 1. This is because the actual seed used in Scenario 1 by the random sampler is not 1 (recall that `RandomSampler` creates its own generator in Scenario 1). To make the output identical, we need to use the same seed:

```py
torch.manual_seed(1)

seed = int(torch.empty((), dtype=torch.int64).random_().item())  # use the same seed as Scenario 1
G = torch.Generator()
G.manual_seed(seed)

ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets, generator=G)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=datasets, 
                        sampler=ran_sampler)
for data in ran_sampler:
  print(data)
```

This code now outputs `1,3,4,0,2`.

## Scenario 3

In Scenario 3, one would expect the result would be the same as Scenario 1 because they use the same random sampler, and both samplers should generate the same seed for their own generators. However, the seeds are actually different because when `DataLoader.__iter__` is called, the below code (defined inside `_BaseDataLoaderIter` class in [torch.utils.data.dataloader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataloader.html)) will also run:

```py
self._sampler_iter = iter(self._index_sampler)
self._base_seed = torch.empty((), dtype=torch.int64).random_(generator=loader.generator).item()
```

Here, `self._index_sampler` is an instance of `BatchSampler` that iterates over `ran_sampler` *if `self._sampler_iter` is iterated over*. In other words, in order for `ran_sampler` to create its own generator, `self._sampler_iter` must be iterated over. After looking at the code of `BatchSampler.__iter__`, you may be wondering why. The reason is because `self._index_sampler.__iter__` is [a Python generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#index-19) which will be executed only if the returned [generator iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator), namely `self._sampler_iter`, is iterated over, which doesn't happen in the code above.

Note that Python generator is not a random number generator like `torch.Generator` but rather [a function that contains `yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#index-19). It's unfortunate that both use the same term which can cause confusion.

Also note that a seed is generated in the code above (`self._base_seed`), which happens **before** `self._sampler_iter` is iterated over. When the loop in Scenario 3 runs, i.e. `self._sampler_iter` is iterated over, `ran_sampler` creates its own generator. Recall from Scenario 1 that this creation executes

```py
seed = int(torch.empty((), dtype=torch.int64).random_().item())
```

where the call `Tensor.random_()` is the *second* call of that method, making `seed` different from that of Scenario 1; Scenario 1 seed is now in `self._base_seed` which is obtained using the *first* call of `Tensor.random_()`. In other words, `self._base_seed` is equal to Scenario 1 seed while `seed` is not. Iterating `ran_sampler` in Scenario 1 twice provides an indication:

```py
torch.manual_seed(1)

ran_sampler = RandomSampler(data_source=datasets)
list(ran_sampler)  # first iteration
for data in ran_sampler:
  print(data)
```

The above code outputs `4,1,3,0,2`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have a few questions about scenario III. 1. I am unsure whether I understand it correctly or not. To let ```ran_sampler``` create its own generator, it must iterate over  ```self._index_sampler```. But what do you mean by ```self._index_sampler.__iter__``` is a Python generator? Where would this generator be used? the sampler already had a generator. 2. What do you mean Scenario 1 seed is now in ```self._base_seed```? Are they the same? However, you also say that ```self._base_seed``` is different from that of Scenario 1.

Comment: @liaoming999 I've added some info and clarifications in the answer.